# Objective C using multiple parameters across classes

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, audio

I have the following declaration in my class called GameManager:

```
-(void)playBackgroundTrack:(NSString*)trackFileName isAmbient:(BOOL*)ambient {

}
```

I want to be able to call

```
[[GameManager sharedGameManager] playBackgroundTrack:BACKGROUND_TRACK isAmbient:NO];
```

or

```
[[GameManager sharedGameManager] playBackgroundTrack:BACKGROUND_TRACK isAmbient:YES];
```

but I am getting a warning:

Semantic Issue: Instance method '-playBackgroundTrack:isAmbient:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

and trying to use the isAmbient parameter crashes.

it works ok if I leave the isAmbient declaration off in both places (but of course I can't use the parameter I want!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use plain `BOOL`, not `BOOL*` in the declaration, like this:

```
-(void)playBackgroundTrack:(NSString*)trackFileName isAmbient:(BOOL)ambient;
```

Comment: Thanks wasn't thinking straight! Need to have more rep to upvote you

Comment: @Eric That's OK, there's no need to upvote this answer. It's a good idea to accept one of the answers, though: it will keep your '%% of accepted answers' high, which is helpful when you ask more questions in the future. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Change the parameter type of isAmbient from `BOOL*` to `BOOL`.

Answer (score 0):

The first piece of code is not a declaration, it's a definition. Declarations are signatures, end with a semicolon and are placed in header files (generally).

You need to then include that class header file with the declaration, so your other class knows the method exists. This will solve the "method not found" issue.

By the way, you probably meant to use a plain BOOL, not a pointer to it. This might be the cause of the crash.

Comment: Thanks wasn't thinking straight! Need to have more rep to upvote you